# I need this 5,000 10,000 340,000 1,000,000 25,000,000 250,000,000

Tags: regex, product, price

```
extension PriceValidator on String {
  bool  isValidPrice () {
    return RegExp(r'^(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*|(\d+))*(\.\d{3})$').hasMatch(this);
  }
}
```

I used this regular expression to get me this data when publishing a product:

5,000

10,000

245,000

1,000,000

25,000,000

240,000,000

and it gives me this data:

5, 10, 245, 1,25,240,

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is looking for numbers that have a period as a thousands seperator but your data is using commas as thousand seperators. You need to replace `\.` with `,`:

`^(\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|(\d+))*(,\d{3})$`

Comment: For some reason, the comma is not activated on the cell phone keyboard, only the period.
I need you to stop throwing me these prices in dollars, 5.00, 150.00